# Generate sub types for graphql-codegen

Tags: typescript, graphql, graphql-codegen

I'm using the [typescript-operations](https://www.the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/plugins/typescript/typescript-operations) from `graphql-codegen` library. But I'm coming from the Apollo deprecated codegen and was loving how they exported types.

for a query like this

```
query MyData {
  viewer {
    id
    username
  }
}
```

I would get this from the apollo-tooling codegen:

```js
export type MyDataQuery_viewer = {
  __typename: 'Viewer';
  id: number;
  username: string;
}
export type MyDataQuery = {
  __typename: 'Query',
  viewer?: MyDataQuery_viewer;
}
```

but in graphql-codegen I'm getting this instead:

```js
export type MyDataQuery = {
  __typename: 'Query',
  viewer?: {
    __typename: 'Viewer';
    id: number;
    username: string;
  };
}
```

Does there exist any configuration to `graphql-codegen` that would give me a type of all nested objects instead of having everything defined in a single type?

Comment: Hey did you land up getting this right? I have to do the same

Answer (score 1):

graphql-codegen will generate separate types for fragments by default, so that's how I solve this issue:

```
fragment ViewerFields on Viewer {
  id
  username
}

query MyData {
  viewer {
    ...ViewerFields
  }
}
```

Will generate

```
export type ViewerFieldsFragment = {
  __typename: 'Viewer';
  id: number;
  username: string;
}

export type MyDataQuery = {
  __typename: 'Query',
  viewer?: {
    __typename: 'Viewer';
    id: number;
    username: string;
  }
}
```

And you can use `ViewerFieldsFragment` in your code.
You can change the `Fragment` suffix if you want with the [omitOperationSuffix](https://ttps://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/plugins/typescript/typescript-operations#omitoperationsuffix) configuration option for the `operations` plugin (which the `typescript-operations` plugin uses behind-the-scenes).

Comment: But this way, the `ViewerFieldsFragment` is not explicitly used in  `MyDataQuery` and an explicit cast with `as` will be necessary.

I have the same issue and I still haven't found a solution

Comment: @Yutsa did you land up finding a solution without having to refactor?

Comment: I've done something like this : `.pipe(map(res => res.data.parcelsGroup?.nodes ?? [])`.

The issue with typing was the `| undefined` so I use the `??` operator to remove the possibility of it being undefined.